# Next JS server side graphql subscriptions

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo, apollo-server

I am currently building chat app in Next JS. I use graphql with Apollo Client in frontend and Apollo Server on backend. Now I want real time updates, but I found out there is **no support** for Subscription in **apollo-server-micro**. As they write here  :
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions#enabling-subscriptions

> Beginning in Apollo Server 3, subscriptions are not supported by the
> "batteries-included" apollo-server package. To enable subscriptions,
> you must first swap to the apollo-server-express package (or any other
> Apollo Server integration package that supports subscriptions).

But I can not use apollo-server-express because I use **NextAuth** for authentication and then I pass it to context:

```
export async function createContext({
  req,
  res,
}: {
  req: NextApiRequest;
  res: NextApiResponse;
}): Promise<Context> {
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  const user = { ...session?.user, _id: session?.userId } as User;
  const db = await dbConnect();
  return {
    user,
    db,
  };
}
```

Thanks for help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, for everyone who wants to use **graphql subscriptions** on server: 
 Use **graphql-yoga** instead :
https://www.graphql-yoga.com/docs/features/subscriptions

My code for **pages/api/graphql.ts** :

```
import { createServer, createPubSub, PubSub } from "@graphql-yoga/node";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { Session } from "next-auth";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";

const pubSub = createPubSub<{
  "user:newMessage": [userId: string, message: Message];
  "user:newChat": [userId: string, chat: Chat];
}>();

export type pubSub = typeof pubSub;

const server = createServer<
  {
    req: NextApiRequest;
    res: NextApiResponse;
  },
  {
    user: User;
    pubSub: any;
  }           
>({
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    const session = await getSession({ req });
    await dbConnect();
    return {
      user: { ...session?.user, _id: session?.userId } as User,
      pubSub,
    };
  },
  schema: {
    typeDefs,
    resolvers: {
      Query,
      Mutation,
      Subscription,
    },
  },
});

export default server;
```